# system.out.print() inside the do while loop is not working

Tags: java

The string (question) in the system.out.print means fill in a number. the question 
    must continue until I fill in 0. the problem is now that the system.out.print inside the do-while loop is not working

my code:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhileLoopNumbers {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner invoer = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int STOP_TEKEN = 0;
    int nummer = invoer.nextInt();

    do {
        System.out.print("Geef een getal: ");
    }
    while (nummer == STOP_TEKEN);
}
}
```

Comment: You're not changing the value of `nummer` inside the loop. Either the loop body executes infinitely (if you entered zero), or one (if you entered something else).

Comment: What do you enter? What do you expect to happen and why?

Comment: As per your current code if you enter 0 first input then it will print the given statement infinite times else you enter any other integer apart from 0 then it will print the given statement once because you are not asking for input inside do block.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the value for nummer variable after the print statement inside the loop. 
like this:

```
    int nummer;
    do {
       System.out.print("Geef een getal: ");
       nummer = invoer.nextInt();
    }while (nummer == STOP_TEKEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn carefully!!! For your case, two scenarios can occur.

First, if your input is anything other than `0`, the `System.out.print()` will run only once. Because, as it is `do-while`, the statements inside `do` will run once and afterwards condition will not match as the number is not equal to `0`, and the loop will break.

Secondly, if your input is `0`, it will lead to **infinite loop** as the condition inside while always satisfies.

**Solution:**

You need to decrease the value of `nummer` in each iteration. Also, change your condition to `!=` in stead of `==`. Try like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner invoer = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int STOP_TEKEN = 0;

    int nummer = invoer.nextInt();

    do {
        System.out.print("Geef een getal: ");
        nummer--;
    }
    while (nummer != STOP_TEKEN);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to provide your code in a readable fashion for us to be able to give effective answers (English). Your loop should end when your input is 0, but right now your code makes it that you are asked for numbers **until you enter anything but zero**.

To correct the code change your while expression to != 0. Also you need to ask the user for a new number inside the loop, not outside of it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner invoer = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int STOP_TEKEN = 0;
        int nummer = 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("Geef een getal: ");
            nummer = invoer.nextInt();
        }
        while (nummer != STOP_TEKEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: how have I created an infinite loop? - perhaps you checked it before my edit

Comment: running the program: https://gyazo.com/b002a4c384dbdedd172fe92df026471e

Answer (score -2):

```
public class WhileLoopNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner invoer = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int STOP_TEKEN = 0;
    int nummer = invoer.nextInt();
    do {
        System.out.print("Geef een getal: ");
        // Assign stdin value to some variable
        nummer = invoer.nextInt();
    } while (nummer != STOP_TEKEN);// check the stdin value with your exit condition
  }
}
```